# Querying array field in MongoDB to contain at least one element of an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Scenario: I have a collection of documents in MongoDB, which have a field called "arrayField" that contains an array of numbers. I have an array of numbers [1, 2, 3], and I want to query this collection to return all documents where the contents of the array field contain *at least one* (not necessarily all) of the elements of [1, 2, 3].
So for instance, if one of the documents has [1, 6, 7] in arrayField, it would be returned.

How to properly formulate the search options for `.find()` to perform such a query? I tried `{'arrayField': { $in: [1, 2, 3]} }`, but that only returns documents where the arrayField has only one element -- just [1] or just [2] or just [3].

Comment: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/syZIvBb4IfB). [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/in/) operator will filter the document that with any value match in the input array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following query will help you

```
db.collection.find({
  "arrayField": {
    "$in": [1, 2, 3]
  }
})
```

This will return all those documents that have either of 1, 2 or 3 in the value of `arrayField` field in your document.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it does work after all -- I just realized that there was a bug in another part of my code. : P

Comment: [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) doc link here, if anyone needed